# Wifi connects to network but not connects to internet

Tags: wireless, firefox

I use ubuntu 10.4
it connects to a my wifi router
but it not make ping or surf the internet
its a belkin n150
I installed the realtek drivers ok

also doesn´t ping the router
In Firefox it says Resolving.. Google.es

```
pruebas@pruebas-desktop:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:15:f2:79:39:a8  
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:16436  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:12 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:12 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0 
          Bytes RX:720 (720.0 B)  TX bytes:720 (720.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW ec:1a:59:10:81:37  
          Direc. inet:192.168.1.77  Difus.:192.168.1.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::ee1a:59ff:fe10:8137/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:37 errores:0 perdidos:51 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:71 errores:0 perdidos:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:4709 (4.7 KB)  TX bytes:9953 (9.9 KB)
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=19 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=20 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=21 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=22 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.77 icmp_seq=25 Destination Host Unreachable


ip route show
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.77  metric 2 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 1000 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static
```

Regards

Comment: I edited with more information

Comment: Your wlan seems to be dropping awfully lots of packets (numero de perdidos) when receiving. What does `sudo iwconfig wlan0` show? Is there something between your computer and the wifi router, like walls, too long distance or sources of radio noise?

Comment: I tried near the router and its doesn´t works and the result of sudo iwconfig wlan0 I will post later   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem, following these steps:

1. I installed `Wicd` from software center
2. Then I uninstalled the network manager with:

   ```
   sudo aptitude uninstall network-manager
   ```
3. reboot, and connected and it´s connect to the internet well